# Sound stops after few seconds after Windows start

Tags: windows, windows-10, audio, realtek-hd-audio

I've replaced motherboard, CPU and RAM. Windows 10 managed to continue working. I've installed Realtek drivers, but the sound stops after 10-15 seconds after boot. Not much in event logger. My USB headset works fine if I switch to it. Weirdly, the speakers still show up in sound device manager as playing. I can switch to headset and hear music. If I switch back it doesn't protest and just pretends the sound is playing throught it. I wanted to somehow force Windows to use generic audio drivers without luck. What can I do? I have Windows license after BizSpark program which allowed me explicitely to use the software as long as I don't reinstall it, so I'd like to avoid reinstalling Windows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Took me 2h in total :-| If you replace motherboard then make sure you uninstalled all software related to old motherboard.

In autostart there was a silent MSI Command Center app. Disabling it fixes issue. Running it manually stops sound and gives you a message that this software is not compatible with current (also MSI) motherboard